# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Basic and Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

what are the differences between the SQL Server 2008 Management Studio BASIC and SQL Server 2008 Management Studio EXPRESS?
Do they are the same?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article about this:

[SQL Server 2008 Management Tools Basic vs Complete Explained....](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/sql-server-2008-management-tools-basic-vs-complete-explained)